# AngularJS ngRoute does not work for me

Tags: angularjs, routes, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I am learning AngularJS these days and I am working on my first application which is also connected with a .NET backend. All is going well, except for one thing:

**I cannot seem to get ngRoute to work properly.**

I have defined my routes in my app.js file like this:

```
var App = angular.module('netshield', ['ngRoute']).config(function 
($httpProvider, $rootScopeProvider) {
});

App.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routes) {
$routes.when("/login", { templateUrl: "login.html", controller: 
"AuthController"})
    .when("/index", { templateUrl: "/partials/dashboard.html", controller: 
"DashboardController"})
    .when("/programs", { templateUrl: "/partials/programs.html", controller: 
"ProgramController"})
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'login'
    });
}]);
```

Now each time I visit http://localhost/netshield/index all is well (except for the partial that does not exist so I suppose we're good).

When I visit http://localhost/netshield/programs I get a **Not Found** error.

My index.html is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="fixed" ng-app="netshield">
<head>
    <!-- Basic -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>NetShield - Control Panel</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="netshield,licensing,system,net,dotnet,license,authentication,serial,code" />
    <meta name="description" content="NetShield - Licensing System">
    <meta name="author" content="Nikolas Andreou">

    <!-- Mobile Metas -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <!-- Web Fonts  -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800|Shadows+Into+Light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Vendor CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />

    <!-- Specific Page Vendor CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/vendor/bootstrap-multiselect/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/vendor/morris.js/morris.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/stylesheets/theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/stylesheets/skins/default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/stylesheets/theme-custom.css">
    <script src="bootstrap/vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Session.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/AuthService.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/AuthController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/DashboardController.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="netshield" <!--ng-controller="DashboardController" ng-init="onLoad()"-->>
    <section class="body">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="logo-container">
                <a href="../" class="logo">
                    <!--<img src="bootstrap/images/logo.png" height="35" alt="Porto Admin" />-->
                </a>
                <div class="visible-xs toggle-sidebar-left" data-toggle-class="sidebar-left-opened" data-target="html" data-fire-event="sidebar-left-opened">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-label="Toggle sidebar"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- start: search & user box -->
            <div class="header-right">
                <div id="userbox" class="userbox">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <figure class="profile-picture">
                            <img src="bootstrap/images/!logged-user.jpg" alt="Joseph Doe" class="img-circle" data-lock-picture="bootstrap/images/!logged-user.jpg" />
                        </figure>
                        <div class="profile-info" data-lock-name="John Doe" data-lock-email="johndoe@okler.com">
                            <span class="name" ng-model="User">{{User.Username}}</span>
                        </div>

                        <i class="fa custom-caret"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="pages-user-profile.html"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Account</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" ng-click="logout($event)"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end: search & user box -->
        </header>
        <!-- end: header -->

        <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <!-- start: sidebar -->
            <aside id="sidebar-left" class="sidebar-left">

                <div class="sidebar-header">
                    <div class="sidebar-title">
                        Navigation
                    </div>
                    <div class="sidebar-toggle hidden-xs" data-toggle-class="sidebar-left-collapsed" data-target="html" data-fire-event="sidebar-left-toggle">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-label="Toggle sidebar"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="nano">
                    <div class="nano-content">
                        <nav id="menu" class="nav-main" role="navigation">
                            <ul class="nav nav-main">
                                <li class="nav-active">
                                    <a href="index">
                                        <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        <span>Dashboard</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-active">
                                    <a href="programs">
                                        <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        <span>My Programs</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-parent">
                                    <a>
                                        <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        <span>My Programs</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="nav nav-children">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="programlist">
                                                View Program List
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="nav-parent">
                                            <a>
                                                Boxed
                                            </a>
                                            <ul class="nav nav-children">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="layouts-boxed.html">
                                                        Static Header
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="layouts-boxed-fixed-header.html">
                                                        Fixed Header
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="layouts-dark.html">
                                                Dark
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="layouts-dark-header.html">
                                                Dark Header
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="layouts-light-sidebar.html">
                                                Light Sidebar
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="layouts-left-sidebar-collapsed.html">
                                                Left Sidebar Collapsed
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="layouts-left-sidebar-scroll.html">
                                                Left Sidebar Scroll
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="nav-parent">
                                            <a>
                                                Left Sidebar Sizes
                                            </a>
                                            <ul class="nav nav-children">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="layouts-sidebar-sizes-xs.html">
                                                        Left Sidebar XS
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="layouts-sidebar-sizes-sm.html">
                                                        Left Sidebar SM
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="layouts-sidebar-sizes-md.html">
                                                        Left Sidebar MD
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="layouts-square-borders.html">
                                                Square Borders
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aside>

            <section role="main" class="content-body">
                <header class="page-header">
                    <h2>Dashboard</h2>

                    <div class="right-wrapper pull-right">
                        <ol class="breadcrumbs">
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html">
                                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li><span>Dashboard</span></li>
                        </ol>

                        <a class="sidebar-right-toggle"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </header>

                <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </section>

        <!-- Vendor -->
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jquery-browser-mobile/jquery.browser.mobile.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/nanoscroller/nanoscroller.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jquery-placeholder/jquery-placeholder.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jqueryui-touch-punch/jqueryui-touch-punch.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jquery-appear/jquery-appear.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/bootstrap-multiselect/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jquery.easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/flot.tooltip/flot.tooltip.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jquery-sparkline/jquery-sparkline.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/raphael/raphael.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/morris.js/morris.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/gauge/gauge.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/snap.svg/snap.svg.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/liquid-meter/liquid.meter.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jqvmap/data/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jqvmap/maps/continents/jquery.vmap.africa.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jqvmap/maps/continents/jquery.vmap.asia.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jqvmap/maps/continents/jquery.vmap.australia.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jqvmap/maps/continents/jquery.vmap.europe.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jqvmap/maps/continents/jquery.vmap.north-america.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/vendor/jqvmap/maps/continents/jquery.vmap.south-america.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/javascripts/theme.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/javascripts/theme.custom.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/javascripts/theme.init.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/javascripts/dashboard/examples.dashboard.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea guys what am I doing wrong? I do not seem to get it to work properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any logs  when you go to `http://localhost/netshield/programs`?

Comment: Also remove not relevant code from example.

Comment: you should include `ngRoute` js file in your app. you injected  `ngRoute` and included  `ui-router` js files

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'ui.router' instead of 'ngRoute'

Comment: why have to use `ui.router`?

Comment: because you are using "angular-ui-router"
 take a look at the doc with an example: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld

Comment: ngRoute is used for an another routing library

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the slashes before the templateUrl path to see if it works

```
templateUrl: "/partials/dashboard.html"
```

becomes 
    templateUrl: "partials/dashboard.html"

Also check if the partials folder is in the same directory as index.html

Also have you include the right ngRoute module in your script tag
Here is a CDN link. Check if this works:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js

Comment: You were right, I had the wrong ngmodule. I added the correct one and it's working to some extent. Some of my routes do not work however, I am now getting redirected to /login (means that .otherwise() is being fired).

Comment: Try adding the index.html view in a seperate partial "home.html" and add this route at the top before the "/login" route to check if it works:
$routes.when("/", { templateUrl: "home.html"})